# Geolocation highly accurate at times but very wrong at other times

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, geolocation

I'm using Ionic and geolocation to get the users coordinates. What I've found is that it's either really accurate or not at all.. Off by 10km or by 30 meters..

This first picture is the **NOT accurate** results:

[image]

The first lat/long is the user location and the second line under it is the lat/long of a landmark. The value below that is the meters away from each other.

As you can see from the first set, geolocation thinks I'm 11km away from this landmark, even though I am only 1km away.

Here is a different picture with the **accurate** results:

[image]

Much better, and using the ionic `coords.accuracy` returns `30` meters away for the accurate one, but something like `47000` for the non-accurate one. For both of these tests I was in the exact same position. The coordinates seem to change randomly every 10-20 minutes..

Here is my code:

```
  let userLocation = {lat: 0, lng: 0}

  this.geolocation.getCurrentPosition({enableHighAccuracy: true}).then((resp) => {
     userLocation.lat = resp.coords.latitude;
     userLocation.lng = resp.coords.longitude;
     console.log(resp.coords.accuracy)
  }).catch((error) => {
    console.log('Error getting location', error);
  });

  getDistance(userLocation, {lat: 35.904912, lng: -79.046913}) //calling the function that returns the distance between each point in meters

  var rad = function(x) {
    return x * Math.PI / 180;
  };

  var getDistance = function(p1, p2) {
    var R = 6378137; // Earth’s mean radius in meter
    var dLat = rad(p2.lat - p1.lat);
    var dLong = rad(p2.lng - p1.lng);
    var a = Math.sin(dLat / 2) * Math.sin(dLat / 2) +
      Math.cos(rad(p1.lat)) * Math.cos(rad(p2.lat)) *
      Math.sin(dLong / 2) * Math.sin(dLong / 2);
    var c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1 - a));
    var d = R * c;
    return d; // returns the distance in meter
  };
```

Is there a way to make this more accurate? Or rather, just show the accurate one? The geolocation seems to randomly change every few minutes..

Answer (score 0):

You can check the "accuracy" value that comes with the geolocation reading. It's in meters i.e. give or take. IOW draw a circle around the lat/lng with a radius of "accuracy" and you're somewhere in the circle.

If it is a new wifi point or telephone tower or you are inside then the accuracy will be lower than if you're outside with GPS. You are free to discard a reading if for example its accuracy is 2x the most accurate reading you've receive previously.

What I do [Here](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B7Rmd3Rn8_hDNW1zSWRoXzBTclU) is very similar but I also set mostAccurate back to high-values if I haven't had a valid GPS update for a while.